Getting False value even on creating a new User instace in Django signal receiver function, Why don't know?
This is my Signal Definition
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_save

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs): 
    user = instance
    if created: 
        print('A new user is created')
    else: 
        print('A new user is not created')
    
    print(sender, user, created)

I am using django-allauth package to authenticate user
Currently i'm using the very simple account authenticating only
Here is the how i have registered signal in my a_users.apps.py:
    def ready(self): 
        print('Ready method is executing')
        import a_users.signals


Here is my projects settings.py file
"""
Django settings for a_core project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 5.1.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-ip6_#ne%exiu=@9a0rbb(_b%9b*oxe+ejyyfm0lmd4+f@v#r()'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]


# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'a_posts',
    # 'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'a_users',
    'django_cleanup.apps.CleanupConfig'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'allauth.account.middleware.AccountMiddleware',
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by email
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'a_core.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'a_core.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/howto/static-files/

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

# Media file configuration (User uploaded images or files)
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') # Where the media files to be stored


# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'


# Allauth Configuration
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/posts/'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True 

ACCOUNT_USERNAME_BLACKLIST = [
    'admin', 'student', 'profile', 
    'category', 'posts','accounts',
    'edit', 'delete',
]


I should get True ideally in the create_profile function whenever i create a new user
But unfortunately i am not getting True rather every time i am getting False Value
I can not understand why it is happening
In order to test whether this problem is persist with other Models I tried a post_save signal for Profile Model and it worked as expected without any issue.
Here is what I wrote for Profile signal
@receiver(post_save, sender=Profile)
def profile_created(sender, instance, created, **kwargs): 
    if created: 
        print("A new profile is created")
    else: 
        print("A new profile is not created")
        print("A new profile is updated")

    print(sender, instance, created)

One more strange thing is happening that when i am creating user through *CLI my signal is not even getting activated.
Thanks in Advance!!

so it prints print('A new user is not created')?

Yes it is,  every single time even upon creation of new User object.

How do you create users? Do you use admin or cli (manage.py)? Did you add a_users to INSTALLED_APPS?

@Pavel1114 I have added a_users in my INSTALLED_APPS I haved mentioned my seetings.py project file in the edited question.

@Pavel1114 I more starange things happens that i fogot to mention that when i am creating user through cli via User.objects.ceate_user(username, email, password) my signal is not event activating that is also one of the problem.

@big_0: yeah, signals are typically not a good tool, I wrote an article about that.

You can start with this:
from django.apps import AppConfig

class YourAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'your_app'

    def ready(self):
        import your_app.signal

Next part more debug tool:

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs): 
    user = instance
    print("User pk:", user.pk)
    print("Created flag:", created)
    
    if created: 
        print('A new user is created')
    else: 
        print('A new user is not created')
    
    print(sender, user, created)

Do you use bulk_create?


I am using django-allauth library for user creation and authentication and authorization. So as of now i don't have any idea what allauth behind the scene is using. I have just started using it and am very beginner in the world of django. by the what do you want to say by bulk_create() and what does it has to with it?  could you please enlighten me?

I am  exactactly doing the same thing what you have suggested so this didn't help me at all.
